# Arithmetic Operations on String And Casting

Tags: java, android, string, operation

I am writing a java code on android studio and I want to do an operation for making a discount percentage to a number that is taken from the edit text as a string and it should be a double or int to use arithmetic operations on it so help me please find the way to solve it.

Comment: What have you done on your own so far?

Comment: Double.parseDouble(String s) and Integer.parseInt(String s). They will post an exception for bad input that you will have to catch.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to convert the string to int or double.

```
String number = editText.getText().toString();
```

just write,

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

now you can use `n` variable as you want.

Answer (score 0):

percentage values are always floating numbers. for that an integer is not going to work well..

try instead a float or a double...

and use a widget that you can set/get without a string convertion, in that way you will avoid pains in the neck with Locale ways to represent those numbers...(is 13.5% the same as 13,5%?) etc

something like:

```
String x = editText.getText().toString();
```

just write:

```
double n = Double.parseDouble(x);
```

here the doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)